# Regex to match a word that has any character preceding it

Tags: regex

Example's: `Hi my name is alarm` Nothing should be matched
`Hi my name is <anything>alarm` Here `<anything>alarm`should be matched, `<anything>` can literally be anything

Comment: No attempt at coding it?

Comment: is `<anything>`'s length more that one character?

Comment: Sorry guys, `\S*alarm` would do it. i guess i shouldn't have hurried into posting the question

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this,

```
\S+alarm
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

Comment: Thank you, I got it right after i posted the quesion!

Comment: @Gokul1794 `Example's: Hi my name is alarm Nothing should be matched` but your regex `\S*alarm` should match `alarm` in this ex.

Answer (score 0):

With a *basic* regular expression:

```
[[:graph:]]\{1,\}alarm$
```

With an *extended* regular expression:

```
[[:graph:]]+alarm$
```

See also *The Open Group Base Specifications*:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html